# How to use fragmentcontainerview in java?

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

I have a container inside MainActivity like that

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main" />
```

and use it like that in main activity

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main, explorefragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It shows this

> Replace the  tag with FragmentContainerView.

how can i replace the code on main activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_screen_navigation"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

that's it u don't need to write anything in main activity

if ur using it with bottom navigation then

```
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
     val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    binding.bnv.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

**and make sure that navigation destination id and items id in bottom navigation view are same**

in JAVA

```
 BottomNavigationView botoomNavigationView = binding.bnv;
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(botoomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController());
```

Comment: how using java sir not kotlin please

Comment: how using java sir not kotlin please